# Converting Double value to Single value, unexpected result

Tags: .net, vb.net, math, numbers, double

I'm using a method that expects a **Single** value to specify a percentage, for example a value of `0.8F` will mean an `80%` and a value of `0.921F` will mean an `92,1%`, but to do the code more readable I preffer to send a **Double** value instead, so for example if I send a value of `80.0R` it should mean `80%` and it should be transtlated to `0.8F` and a value of `80.5R` should mean `80,5%` and should be translated to `0.805F` (if my calcs are good) and a value of `100.0R` should be translated to `1.0F`.

My problem is that when I try to convert a Double Value for example `80.0R` to Single I get a bad translation, in that case I get an `80.0F`, but should be `0.8F`.

What I'm doing wrong?

This is the method:

```
Private Function FindImage(ByVal BaseImage As Bitmap,
                           ByVal ImageToFind As Bitmap,
                           ByVal Similarity As Double) As AForge.Imaging.TemplateMatch()

    Dim SingleSimilarity As Single

    ' Translate the readable similarity percent value to Single value.
    Select Case Similarity

        Case Is < 0.1R, Is > 100.0R ' Value is out of range.
            Throw New Exception(String.Format("Similarity value of '{0}' is out of range, range is from '0.1' to '100.0'",
                                              CStr(Similarity)))

        Case Is = 100.0R ' Identical image comparission.
            SingleSimilarity = 1.0F

        Case Else ' Image with similarity comparission.
            SingleSimilarity = Convert.ToSingle(...) ' Here goes bad.

    End Select

    ...

    ' This only accepts a Single value:
    Dim tm As New AForge.Imaging.ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(SingleSimilarity)

    ...

End Function
```

Usage:

```
Me.FindImage(Parameter1, Parameter2, Similarity:=80.5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Convert.ToSingle()` simply converts your number as is from `Double` to `Single`. It does not make any modifications to the value. So `80.5R` becomes `80.5F` - no change in value.

You will need to actually write the conversion to convert from percentage - something like this:

```
Case Else
    SingleSimilarity = Convert.ToSingle(Similarity) / 100.0F
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest code i have ever seen.

```
SingleSimilarity = single.parse(Similarity) / 100.0F
```

Comment: you mean what kind of details you need? @SGG?

Comment: ?@SGG what kind of details you want?